# jQuery UI - accordion - sortable issue

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-sortable

I've encountered a problem with the sortable interaction of accordion. It should be possible to drag the `<h3>` elements and change their order. I tried to use the function from the official demo ([here](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#sortable)), but the sort doesn't "work".

Here is the CodePen for the full example: https://codepen.io/pprunesquallor/pen/awWREP

(My script does include other things (for icons, collapsing and resizing), but I wouldn't want to exclude those as I want to build on it.)

```
  $( function() {

    var icons = {
      header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
      activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
    };

    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        icons: icons,
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "fill"
    });

    $( "#accordion-resizer" ).resizable({
      minHeight: 140,
      minWidth: 200,
      resize: function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "refresh" );
      }
    });

  $("#accordion")
    .accordion({
      header: " > h3"
    })
    .sortable({
      axis: "y",
      handle: "h3",
      stop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.children("h3").triggerHandler("focusout");
        $(this).accordion("refresh");
      }
    });

  });
```

I found a similar problem here by another user, his issue was not enclosing the `<h3>` and `<p>` elements inside of an additional `<div>` so I'm assuming this also has to do with "> div > h3" and my HTML, but I tried all combinations and none worked...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your item as below, .group field missing:

```js
   
  $( function() {

    var icons = {
      header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
      activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
    };

$("#accordion")
    .accordion({
      icons: icons,
      collapsible: true,
      heightStyle: "fill",
      header: "> div > h3"
    })
    .sortable({
      axis: "y",
      handle: "h3",
      stop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.item.children("h3").triggerHandler("focusout");
        $(this).accordion("refresh");
      }
    });
    $( "#accordion-resizer" ).resizable({
      minHeight: 140,
      minWidth: 200,
      resize: function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "refresh" );
      }
    });

  

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<body>

  <div id="accordion-resizer" class="ui-widget-content">
    <div id="accordion">
      <div class="group">
        <h3>I'm open by default</h3>
        <div>
          <p>
            One
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <h3>Open me!</h3>
        <div>
          <p>
            Two
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <h3>Open me, you won't regret it!</h3>
        <div>
          <p>
            Three
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <h3>I'm the one you're looking for!!</h3>
        <div>
          <p>
            JK, nothing in here
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Govind, thank you! Sorry, but I don't understand what you did there. You didn't change anything apart from "header: "> div > h3"" in the javascript and added class group in the html?

Comment: Yes I just made these changes

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that you excluded this part from my code: $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        icons: icons,
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "fill"
    }); - (so it is no longer collapsible) could you please explain why? I notice it break the accordion if I include it but I don't understand why...

Comment: Because you are trying to reinit according, I've all your options in single instance.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks a lot!